# Conditional compilation by changing the value of macro

Tags: c, compilation, macros, conditional-statements

i want to compile a program with conditional compilation without redefining the macro , for Example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define X 1
int main ()
{
    #ifdef X
    printf("HI\n");
    #else
    printf("Hello\n");
    #endif // X
    return 0;
}
```

if i change the value of the macro to be 0 the else part is not getting executed , rather the if part alone is getting executed , if i change the macro or if statement alone the else part is being complied , my question is , is there a way to condition compile by reading the value of  macro ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `#if` instead.

```
#if X
printf("HI\n");     // will be compiled if X is anything but 0
#else
printf("Hello\n");  // will be compiled if X is 0
#endif // X
```